# How to set a Fill value

Tags: html, css

Like we have a way to set opacity in CSS, how do you set Fill? Like in Photoshop?

My problem is, a client of mine has asked me to code his PSD for him, he has set opacity to 100% and fill to 0% which make it almost transparent! And I have no idea how to do that in HTML/CSS.

Comment: you mean gradient effect from 100% black to 0% black?

Comment: you have to check `rgba` in css.

Comment: @KheemaPandey can you suggest the code of what are you trying to say? I will test it.

Comment: @Arjun can you suggest me how to do it on a image?

Comment: I've posted a comment. let me know if this you are looking?

Comment: The main difference between Opacity and Fill has to do with Photoshop’s layer styles. If you haven’t added any effects (styles) to your layer, like a stroke, drop shadow, bevel and emboss or outer glow, you’ll get the same results when lowering either the Opacity or Fill values

Comment: rgb(0,255,0, 0.3) in this way you can decrease the the opacity, 0.3 is the opacity value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hassan,
 Is this you are looking for?

```
#grad1
{
height:200px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

<div id="grad1"></div>
```

let me know if you are looking for this kind example. check the [Demo link](http://jsbin.com/notiviso/1/)

Comment: Its close, can you make it totally black?

Comment: okay here is the updated Demo link.
`http://jsbin.com/notiviso/1/`

Comment: If this solve your problem than you can accept this answer by clicking on green checkmark, so  other people can get benefited.

Comment: glad; I can put a smile on your face.